# Mask Edit : Unknown identifier 'TEXT'

Tags: pascalscript

I am using custom control (let's say customctrl) which is inherited from TCustomMask edit. Whenever I use customctrl.text it show the error "[Error] (16:31): Unknown identifier 'TEXT'". But if i used the customctrl.GetTextLen it works fine. In order to fix this issue, I added SIRegister_Mask in compile import and RIRegister_Mask(CL)and RIRegister_Mask_Routines(S) available in unit uPSI_Mask.pas under the third party but it still shows the above error.

CompileTime import

```
  SIRegister_Std(CL);
  SIRegister_Classes(CL, true);
  SIRegister_Graphics(CL, true);
  SIRegister_Controls(CL);
  SIRegister_stdctrls(CL);
  **SIRegister_Mask(CL);**
  SIRegister_Forms(CL);      _
```

RunTime import

```
  RIRegister_Std(CL);
  RIRegister_stdctrls(CL);
  RIRegister_Mask(CL);
  RIRegister_Mask_Routines(S);
```

Edit: I observed that even the FocusControl method is reported as unidentified even though it is part of uPSR_forms and uPSC_forms.

I am not able to figure out the solution and need help.

Thanks!